# Highlighting a Grid row containing controls using MouseOver / MouseEnter events

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to find a good way to highlight a `Grid` row when the mouse pointer hovers over it.  I have a `Rectangle` in each row which I'm changing the opacity of by using triggers on the `Rectangle.MouseEnter` and `Rectangle.MouseLeave` events.  The problem is that when the row contains `ComboBox` controls, `TextBox` controls etc., the `Rectangle.MouseLeave` event is fired when the mouse hovers over it *(row 0 in the example)*.  The same goes for the `IsMouseOver` event.  I can avoid this by setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `False` *(row 1 in the example)*, but that sort of defeats the purpose (duh).

On a side note, I notice that the `Grid`'s `IsMouseOver` event is `True` even though the mouse hovers over a control with `IsHitTestVisible` set to `True`.

So how can I get `IsMouseOver` or `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events on the `Rectangle` that won't be affected by the mouse hovering over a control in the `Grid` row?

Or for that matter, if someone has a better approach to achieve this behavior, I'm all ears.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MouseOverHighlightStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Opacity)"
                                                    To="0.3" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Opacity)"
                                                    To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MouseOverHighlightStyle}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: why not give the style to your `stackpanel`?

Comment: I'm not always using `StackPanel`'s to contain the controls.  But would that change anything in regards to the events?

Comment: i think the answer is in the dupe i just posted :-)

Comment: Hmm..  Good catch!  I couldn't find any similar cases.  I'll test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve your problem:

1. I agree with @Mike, style the StackPanel right away.
2. Rectangle is not necessary, instead make sure you put background to transparent, so it will pickup the MouseOver event/property change.

The code would look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}"> <!-- this will apply to all StackPanels-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/> <!--without this, IsMouseOver is not triggered over the whitespace area-->
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Rectangle is removed-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"> <!-- StackPanel will use the style defined in the Window.Resources-->
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation, this is the solution I ended up with to also get the animations:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StackPanelMouseOverHighlightStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="PanelBackgroundColor" Color="Red" Opacity="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"
                                                To="0.3" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"
                                                To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelMouseOverHighlightStyle}">
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"  Style="{StaticResource StackPanelMouseOverHighlightStyle}">
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <ComboBox Height="30" Width="100" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```